# JAVA - I have 2 windows and i need to close 1 window

Tags: java

My java program is opening new window when i press one button in first window. Then i need to close first window. When i try to close first window with `System.exit(0);` it closes second window. I tryed `setVisible(false);` then first window doesn't close. Please help!

Whole code:

```
public class NameChooser extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public NameChooser() {
    RunNC();
}

public final void RunNC() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your name that will be shown in game!");
    label.setBounds(20, 10, 500, 25);
    panel.add(label);

    JLabel error = new JLabel("");
    error.setForeground(Color.red);
    panel.add(error);

    JTextField name = new JTextField(30);
    name.setBounds(50, 40, 180, 25);
    panel.add(name);

    JButton playButton = new JButton( new AbstractAction("Play") {
        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String enteredname = name.getText();

            if("".equals(enteredname)) {
                error.setVisible(true);
                error.setText("Invalid name!");
                error.setBounds(105, 95, 100, 25);
                System.out.println("Invalid name!");
            }

            else if(enteredname.length() > 10) {
                error.setVisible(true);
                error.setText("Name cant have more than 10 characters!");
                error.setBounds(25, 95, 600, 25);
                System.out.println("Name cant have more than 10 characters!");
            }

            error.setVisible(false);

            GameWindow game = new GameWindow();
            game.StartGame();

            // I need to close window on this line!
        }
    });

    playButton.setBounds(110, 70, 60, 25);
    panel.add(playButton);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: where is your code? have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused because System.exit() causes the Java VM to terminate completely - and both of your windows are running on the same VM instance.

Use Jframe.[dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose())() instead on the one you want to close.

Comment: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dispose() from the type Window` error

Comment: @Neonry sorry - you didn't provide any sample code so I couldn't print a complete statement with context.  You need to call it on the *instance* of the JFrame.  So if JFrame frame = new JFrame(); you should call **frame**.dispose() to get rid of it.  Don't forget to mark this answer correct if it solved this issue:)

Answer (score -1):

```
System.exit(0);
```

doesn't "close a window", it terminates the JVM in which your entire application is running, hence, it terminates the entire application.

If we're talking about JFrames, try by using the `dispose()` method to close your seperate screens.

If you want us to comment on your `setVisible(false)`, show us the code where you call it, it might be you're calling it on the wrong variable.

Comment: I would prefer not to use `setVisible(false)` to close the window. It just hides the window from the screen but still holds the memory.

Comment: which is where the dispose() method comes in.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and should be a comment, as it is a request for clarification.  The question is not answerable in its present state as it contains no code.